# Starting a new Activity OnClick (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

I'm trying to start an activity on the onclick of a button but can't seem te get it to work.
The app freezes when the button is pressed.

This is the code I use:

From the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="ExecJson"
    android:text="Button" />
```

In the current Activity:

```
           public void ExecJson (View view) {           
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Listviewer.class); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And the Activity I want to start:

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.json;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest.R;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Listviewer extends ListActivity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://oranjelan.nl/deelnemers.txt");

        try{

            JSONArray  deelnemers = json.getJSONArray("deelnemers");

            for(int i=0;i<deelnemers.length();i++){                     
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = deelnemers.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Alias: " +  e.getString("alias"));
                map.put("city", "Woonplaats: " +  e.getString("woonplaats"));
                map.put("sex", "Geslacht: " +  e.getString("geslacht"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }   



        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "city", "sex" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle2, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Listviewer.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Provide the LOGCAT from execution!

Comment: Have you added the new activity to the manifest file ?

Comment: The application freezes because the button is working fine the problem is in the listviewer activity.

Comment: can u post logcat? then only we can know d actual problem..

Comment: Whenever you extend any class with ListActivity then don't use setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder); ...its not allowed...and may be watever prob you are facing is because of this...

Comment: Have u initialized button in activity?

Comment: I recommend you to call any webservices in asyntask. The android dosent allow network operations to happen in the main thread because of strict mode thread policy since android version 3.

Comment: Hmm Im really new to this and it was actually not in the manifest file yet :D so its solved now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be because you are trying to get web request (Network related operation) on your Activity Listviewer's MainUI thread.

From this line,

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://oranjelan.nl/deelnemers.txt");
```

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this web request and try again..

Answer (score 0):

The reason the app is freezing when you start the new `Activity` is because you're running network related operations on the UI-thread. An `AsyncTask` would be easy to implement, and would probably also get rid of your issue.

Example:

```
public class AsyncLoading extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    // Attributes
    private Context mContext;
    private ListView mListView;
    private List<Map<String, String>> mListData;

    public AsyncLoading(Context c, ListView lv) {
        mContext = c;
        mListView = lv;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://oranjelan.nl/deelnemers.txt");
            JSONArray  deelnemers = json.getJSONArray("deelnemers");
            for(int i=0;i<deelnemers.length();i++){                  

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = deelnemers.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Alias: " +  e.getString("alias"));
                map.put("city", "Woonplaats: " +  e.getString("woonplaats"));
                map.put("sex", "Geslacht: " +  e.getString("geslacht"));

                mListData.add(map);            
            }   
            return true;

        } catch(JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if( result ) {

            mListView.setAdapter(

                new SimpleAdapter(
                    mContext,
                    mListData,
                    R.layout.main,
                    new String[] { "name", "city", "sex" },
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle2, R.id.item_subtitle }
                )

            );
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No data found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```